# Render failed - Davinci Resolve 16

Tags: video-editor, editing, davinci-resolve

I have a problem with exporting an old timeline from Resolve. In 15 it worked fine, but I did some changes in an old composition and want to export the updated version. Error message says:

> Render job 1 failed as the current clip could not be processed. The Fusion composition on the current frame or clip could not be processed successfully.

The fix of copying and moving to a new time project hasn't worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

In the 'Deliver' panel, under the Advanced Settings, try enabling/ticking “Use render cached images”.

Comment: The "Use render cached images" solution worked for me. I also output to H264 and used optimized media. Thanks a lot. I was really stuck with this problem some time ago, now it cropped up again. I am on the free version of Resolve, btw.

Answer (score 1):

Try transcoding and relinking the media: File → Media Management.